# variables are not stored in class with nodejs application

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a question about parameters that are not referenced correctly I assume.
I pass in a function Foo a object. This is stored in the this object so we can use it later. That is the intension. But when it is used, the value is not stored in that variable. What do I do wrong ?

File Foo.js:

```
function Foo(bar) {
    this.barr = bar;
}

Foo.prototype.inbar() {
     console.log("Barr= ", this.barr);
     return true;
}

module.exports.Foo = Foo;
```

File Test.js

```
var foo = require("Foo.js").Foo; 
var test;
var o_obj;

function funcObject(){
    this.id = function id() { return "AnId"; };
};

o_obj = new funcObject();

test = new foo([o_obj]);
test.inbar();
```

Output on console = undefined

Comment: First, the declaration of `inbar` is not valid JavScript (it should be `Foo.prototype.inbar = function() {...`). When I change it to a proper function, the code works as you intended, so your example doesn't seem to be complete.

Comment: Indeed my problem was a typo and the example should be like you where saying. thankx